# How can $f$ will be continious?

Tags: general-topology

Prove  that  $\mathbb{R}_k$  is not path connected

i have found the link : http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~brendle/topology/sol-08.pdf

My confusion  is here [image]

I have  read on theorem in Munkre Topology  it is wriiten  that  $f : X ' \rightarrow X$  will be continious  if  $T'$ will finer than $ T$

Here K -topology is finer than usual Topology    How can  $f$  will  be continious ? , as $[0,1]$ is usual  and $\mathbb{R}_k $ is  K topology  that mean here   usual map  to  K-topology

If  $K$ -topology  map to usual  topology than i can said that  $f $  will be continious

My confusion   why  $f$ is  continious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topology $\tau'$ on $X$ is finer than $\tau$ if and only if the tautological map $id^{\tau'}_{\tau}:(X,\tau')\to (X,\tau)$, $id^{\tau'}_{\tau}(x)=x$, is continuous. In your case, the map $id^K_{\text{std}}\circ f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is continuous because it is composition of $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R_K$ and the continuous map $id^K_{\text{std}}:\Bbb R_K\to \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

If the inverse image of every open set in the $K$-topology is open, then a fortiori the inverse image of very open set in the usual topology is open.  I think you are comparing a case where the topologies on the domain of the function are different, but here it is the topologies on the range that differ.

Comment: here $[0,1]$ is  usual and $\mathbb{R}_K$  as   usual map  to k -topology  so  i was  thinking  that  f will not  continious